# Thermostat common low voltage

Tags: wiring, hvac, low-voltage

My thermostat failed and I am replacing it with a Honeywell Lyric T6 pro.

The previous configuration had G,W,R connected with Rc jumpered.  The thermostat wire was 5-wire, 22ga I think.  I used an extra wire to run power from the transformer (28vac) up to the common.  However I still cannot get it to turn on.  I tried checking voltage at the thermostat but I'm actually not sure how to check without access to the neutral.  Using any ground I could find I was getting 6-7 volts.  I'm sure this is not valid but regardless, its not
turning on.

Also,  There is a C terminal on the furnace board.  The instructions make it sound like the wire should go straight from the transformer to the thermostat.  Should anything be connected to the C terminal on the board?

Comment: Pictures of the wiring at the 'stat and furnace. Brand/model of the stat & furnace. These things are always helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this case was simple since the furnace board had an unused C terminal, I just connected a spare wire to it and ran it to the C terminal on the thermostat.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run both, the R and C from the transformer to thermostat to have 24 volt at thermostat that it needs for its operation.

The G is the Fan (indoor blower)

The Y is cooling (Compressor ON)

The W is heating (Furnace on Gas or electric)

Comment: I thought R was the signal wire for the heat.  Doesn't it need to come from the board?

Comment: R comes from the board (transformer) so does the C. The W is for heat command